# SQL query for List all existing databases and users

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need an SQL query to find in one table:

- All existing databases.
- All Users and their roles for each database.

I tried to list the database roles with the following query, but I get the result only for one database.

```
select
  rp.name as database_role,
  mp.name as database_user
from
  sys.database_role_members drm
  join sys.database_principals rp
    on (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
  join sys.database_principals mp
    on (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id)
```

Comment: What did you tried so far? What is the problem you encountered and should be clarified?

Comment: need more explanation...!

Comment: use HRD
select rp.name as database_role, mp.name as database_user
from sys.database_role_members drm
join sys.database_principals rp on (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
join sys.database_principals mp on (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id)

Comment: I tried use this query and I get result for one databases. But I can't use it in the main folder or in one Execute to get all databases and users.

Comment: Just a tip to get started: [sp_msforeachdb](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/26/sql-server-list-all-the-tables-for-all-databases-using-system-tables/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the results for the current database, because this is how catalog views work. On the other hand, you can use the three-part name to query other databases' catalog views.

For example, if you want to select the tables from the `msdb` database, you can use the following syntax:

```
SELECT * FROM msdb.sys.tables
```

**Query on all databases**

The next problem is to write a query for all databases. Unfortunately there is no reference for 'all databases', but there is an undocumented stored procedure which can help. This is the `sp_MSforeachdb`.

*Please note, that the phrase `undocumented` means that the implementation and the parameter list could change, or the feature could be removed at any time, so be careful when you are using any undocumented features!*

The query to list all roles looks like this:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
    @command1 = '
        INSERT INTO ##RoleTemp (db, database_role, database_user)
        SELECT
            ''?'' AS db,
            rp.NAME AS database_role,
            mp.NAME AS database_user
        FROM
            [?].sys.database_role_members drm
            INNER JOIN [?].sys.database_principals rp
                ON (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
            INNER JOIN [?].sys.database_principals mp
                ON (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id);
    '
```

The SP will iterate throught on all databases and runs the query for each database. The question mark in the above query will be replaced with the actual database name.

**Merging the datasets**

There is a minor problem with this query: it will return with multiple results (one result per databases).

The last step is to merge all results into one result. The `sp_MSforeachdb` has more parameters than the above one. To solve the multi-result problem, you can use the `@precommand` and `@postcommand` parameters.

The query provided by the `@precommand` parameter will run only once, before the main query, and `@postcommand` will run at the end.

Knowing this, the final query will be:

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb
    @precommand = N'CREATE TABLE ##RoleTemp (db VARCHAR(MAX), database_role VARCHAR(MAX), database_user VARCHAR(MAX));',
    @command1 = '
        INSERT INTO ##RoleTemp (db, database_role, database_user)
        SELECT
            ''?'' AS db,
            rp.NAME AS database_role,
            mp.NAME AS database_user
        FROM
            [?].sys.database_role_members drm
            INNER JOIN [?].sys.database_principals rp
                ON (drm.role_principal_id = rp.principal_id)
            INNER JOIN [?].sys.database_principals mp
                ON (drm.member_principal_id = mp.principal_id);
    ',
    @postcommand = 'SELECT * FROM ##RoleTemp; DROP TABLE ##RoleTemp;'
```

This will crate a temporary table, then inserts all results from all databases into that temp table. The postcommand selects all records inserted into the temp table, then drops the temp table.

I hope, this will help to solve your problem.